# How to loop inside a json dict and select specific index with Python

Tags: python, json, api

I'd like to print out for my project, the weather forecast for 5 days. When I make my request I get this huge JSON dictionary with the same parameter repeat for five different days and different times.

This is part of the dict.

```
    {'city': {'coord': {'lat': 43.55, 'lon': 13.1667},
          'country': 'IT',
          'id': 3183087,
          'name': 'Provincia di Ancona',
          'population': 478319,
          'sunrise': 1626147487,
          'sunset': 1626202058,
          'timezone': 7200},
 'cnt': 40,
 'cod': '200',
 'list': [{'clouds': {'all': 97},
           'dt': 1626188400,
           'dt_txt': '2021-07-13 15:00:00',
           'main': {'feels_like': 31.67,
                    'grnd_level': 990,
                    'humidity': 47,
                    'pressure': 1006,
                    'sea_level': 1006,
                    'temp': 30.75,
                    'temp_kf': -4.44,
                    'temp_max': 35.19,
                    'temp_min': 30.75},
           'pop': 0,
           'sys': {'pod': 'd'},
           'visibility': 10000,
           'weather': [{'description': 'overcast clouds',
                        'icon': '04d',
                        'id': 804,
                        'main': 'Clouds'}],
           'wind': {'deg': 211, 'gust': 12.79, 'speed': 9.41}},
          {'clouds': {'all': 97},
           'dt': 1626199200,
           'dt_txt': '2021-07-13 18:00:00',
           'main': {'feels_like': 30.93,
                    'grnd_level': 990,
                    'humidity': 50,
                    'pressure': 1006,
                    'sea_level': 1006,
                    'temp': 29.92,
                    'temp_kf': 1.67,
                    'temp_max': 29.92,
                    'temp_min': 28.25},
           'pop': 0.12,
           'sys': {'pod': 'd'},
           'visibility': 10000,
           'weather': [{'description': 'overcast clouds',
                        'icon': '04d',
                        'id': 804,
                        'main': 'Clouds'}],
           'wind': {'deg': 246, 'gust': 10.79, 'speed': 6.88}},
          {'clouds': {'all': 81},
           'dt': 1626210000,
           'dt_txt': '2021-07-13 21:00:00',
           'main': {'feels_like': 27.85,
                    'grnd_level': 991,
                    'humidity': 57,
                    'pressure': 1007,
                    'sea_level': 1007,
                    'temp': 26.98,
                    'temp_kf': 1.89,
                    'temp_max': 26.98,
                    'temp_min': 25.09},
           'pop': 0.26,
           'sys': {'pod': 'n'},
           'visibility': 10000,
           'weather': [{'description': 'broken clouds',
                        'icon': '04n',
                        'id': 803,
                        'main': 'Clouds'}],
           'wind': {'deg': 237, 'gust': 14.36, 'speed': 7.51}},
          {'clouds': {'all': 37},
           'dt': 1626220800,
           'dt_txt': '2021-07-14 00:00:00',
           'main': {'feels_like': 19.41,
                    'grnd_level': 993,
                    'humidity': 61,
                    'pressure': 1009,
                    'sea_level': 1009,
                    'temp': 19.78,
                    'temp_kf': 0,
                    'temp_max': 19.78,
                    'temp_min': 19.78},
           'pop': 0.26,
           'sys': {'pod': 'n'},
           'visibility': 10000,
           'weather': [{'description': 'scattered clouds',
                        'icon': '03n',
                        'id': 802,
                        'main': 'Clouds'}],
           'wind': {'deg': 273, 'gust': 6.66, 'speed': 4.17}},
          {'clouds': {'all': 0},
           'dt': 1626231600,
           'dt_txt': '2021-07-14 03:00:00',
           'main': {'feels_like': 16.32,
                    'grnd_level': 993,
                    'humidity': 64,
                    'pressure': 1010,
                    'sea_level': 1010,
                    'temp': 16.9,
                    'temp_kf': 0,
                    'temp_max': 16.9,
                    'temp_min': 16.9},
```

The value that I want print out are name, city, wind, dt_txt. The first two value are always the same but the other two have different index value.
I wrote this simple loop for start to how to do it but i realize that the index value change (is not always the same counting, i tried also to repeat the loop on a specific index but didn't work) in the dict and i don't know how to solve this problem. Ofcourse I can do manualy save all the 'time' and 'wind' value in variables but is a huge work.

time = list_of_data['list'][2]['dt_txt']

```
data_fore = [time]

for cast in data_fore:
    print(cast)
```

So, how can i loop this value from this dict and print out the values that i need?

I hope i was clear and thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, Dictionaries are not ordered^. There is nothing like index in a Standard Python Dictionary.

To achieve what you want, the code below should do (I assume, the keys are always the same):

```py
for each in result["list"]:
    print("_" * 50)
    print("wind", each["wind"])
    print("city", result["city"])
    print("name", result["city"]["name"])
    print("dt_txt", each["dt_txt"])
```

Running above code on the data in the question results in this:

```
__________________________________________________
wind {'deg': 211, 'gust': 12.79, 'speed': 9.41}
city {'coord': {'lat': 43.55, 'lon': 13.1667}, 'country': 'IT', 'id': 3183087, 'name': 'Provincia di Ancona', 'population': 478319, 'sunrise': 1626147487, 'sunset': 1626202058, 'timezone': 7200}
name Provincia di Ancona
dt_txt 2021-07-13 15:00:00
__________________________________________________
wind {'deg': 246, 'gust': 10.79, 'speed': 6.88}
city {'coord': {'lat': 43.55, 'lon': 13.1667}, 'country': 'IT', 'id': 3183087, 'name': 'Provincia di Ancona', 'population': 478319, 'sunrise': 1626147487, 'sunset': 1626202058, 'timezone': 7200}
name Provincia di Ancona
dt_txt 2021-07-13 18:00:00
```

> ^Python 3.6+ preserves the insertion order of a dictionary. However in this case, it's coming from an API, order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Dictionaries are **ordered** from Python 3.6 onwards.

Comment: Yes, they are, but that is only when it is created within the program. In this case, the dictionary comes from an external API call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `d` is your dictionary, this code prints the data you need.

You can just iterate over `d['list']` and extract the data as they are also a `dictionary`.

```
print(f"Name: {d['city']['name']}")
print(f"City: {d['city']}")
for i in d['list']:
    print(f"Wind: {i.get('wind')}")
    print(f"Time: {i.get('dt_txt')}")
    print('\n')
```

```
Sample Output:

Name: Provincia di Ancona
City: {'coord': {'lat': 43.55, 'lon': 13.1667}, 'country': 'IT', 'id': 3183087, 'name': 'Provincia di Ancona', 'population': 478319, 'sunrise': 1626147487, 'sunset': 1626202058, 'timezone': 7200}


Wind: {'deg': 211, 'gust': 12.79, 'speed': 9.41}
Time: 2021-07-13 15:00:00


Wind: {'deg': 246, 'gust': 10.79, 'speed': 6.88}
Time: 2021-07-13 18:00:00


Wind: {'deg': 237, 'gust': 14.36, 'speed': 7.51}
Time: 2021-07-13 21:00:00


Wind: {'deg': 273, 'gust': 6.66, 'speed': 4.17}
Time: 2021-07-14 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I named the dictionary `json`

```
print('Name:',json['city']['name'])
print('City:',json['city'])
print('#'*50)

for item in json['list']:
    print('Wind:', item['wind'])
    print('dt_txt:', item['dt_txt'])
    print('-'*50)
```

Output:

```
Name: Provincia di Ancona
City: {'coord': {'lat': 43.55, 'lon': 13.1667}, 'country': 'IT', 'id': 3183087, 'name': 'Provincia di Ancona', 'population': 478319, 'sunrise': 1626147487, 'sunset': 1626202058, 'timezone': 7200}
##################################################
Wind: {'deg': 211, 'gust': 12.79, 'speed': 9.41}
dt_txt: 2021-07-13 15:00:00
--------------------------------------------------
Wind: {'deg': 246, 'gust': 10.79, 'speed': 6.88}
dt_txt: 2021-07-13 18:00:00
--------------------------------------------------
Wind: {'deg': 237, 'gust': 14.36, 'speed': 7.51}
dt_txt: 2021-07-13 21:00:00
--------------------------------------------------
Wind: {'deg': 273, 'gust': 6.66, 'speed': 4.17}
dt_txt: 2021-07-14 00:00:00
--------------------------------------------------
```